# how to change the sprite position based on move?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

i am having 20 sprite in my scene i had arranged my sprite like below.

```
       o    o    o   o   o    o    o

       o    o    o   .   o    o    o 

       o    o    o   o   o    o    o
```

o-->my ball sprite
  .-->my empty sprite

when i move 2nd sprite in 2nd row to the empty sprite,my 3rd sprite wants to removed and empty space should be added there.
Like wise i want to move any sprite to empty position (horizontal move,Vertical Move,Diagonal move)the middle sprite wants to removed.
Can anyone help me for this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Code would be helpful.

Comment: I need your idea,Tell me how can i proceed.Because i am new to cocos2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

In .h declare a global sprite variable,

```
CCSprite *movingBall;
```

In .m, in init,

```
movingBall = nil;
```

In `touchesBegan`,

```
if(!movingBall)
{
  for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
  {
     CCSprite *currentSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i+tagOffset];

     if(CGRectIntersectsPoint([currentSprite boundingBox],touchPoint))   
     {
        // get moving sprite touched

        if(movingBall.position.x == emptySprite.position.x+(2*xDistance) || movingBall.position.x == emptySprite.position.x-(2*xDistance) || movingBall.position.y == emptySprite.position.y+(2*yDistance) || movingBall.position.y == emptySprite.position.y -(2*yDistance))
        {
          movingBall = (CCSPrite *)currentSprite;
          Break;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

In touchesMoved,

```
if(!movingBall)
{
  return;
}


movingBall.position = touchedPoint;

for(int i = 0; i<20; i++)
{
   CCSprite *currentSprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:i+tagOffset];

   if(CGRectIntersectsRect([movingBall boundingBox],[currentSprite boundingBox]))   
   {
      // current sprite touched
      if(currentSprite.tag == emptySprite.tag)
      {
        movingBall.position = emptySprite.position;

        [self removeChild:currentSprite];
        Break;
      }

   }
}
```

In touchesEnded,

```
  if(!movingBall)
  {
    return;
  }

  movingBall = nil;
```

Comment: I want this to be done when my TouchesMoved at the TouchesEnd Revoming and adding of new sprite to be done.Can you help me with Elabrated code please.

Comment: if(currentSprite.tag == emptySprite.tag)
      {
        movingBall.position = emptySprite.position;

        [self removeChild:currentSprite];
        Break;
      }      In this step How can i check (currentSprite.tag == emptySprite.tag).How to add tag value for empty sprite

Comment: Anusha i need your help to solve this problem please help me.